# Wicket 6 modal window parent page update

Tags: modal-dialog, parent, updatemodel, wicket-6

I have two modal window scenarios that worked with Wicket 1.4 but no longer work with Wicket 6.

Case 1
Modal1 inserts an item into list on parent page, then closes.
Callback on parent page refreshes the list using target.add(container)
I can see that the callback is firing but the refresh no longer has any effect.

```
modal.setWindowClosedCallback(new ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        logger.info("Running Modal1 closed callback... ");
        logger.info("AjaxRequestTarget: " + target.getPageClass().getName());
        target.add(sampleListView);
        modal.close(target);
    }
});
```

Case 2
Parent page defines two modal windows.
Callback for Modal2 launches Modal1.
I can see that the callback is firing but Modal2 is no longer launching.

```
modal.setWindowClosedCallback(new ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    logger.info("Running Modal2 closed callback... ");
    logger.info("AjaxRequestTarget: " + target.getPageClass().getName());
        if (originalSample != null){
            logger.info("originalSample is not null");
            ...do some stuff...
            modal1.show(target);
        }else{
             modal.close(target);
        }
}
});
```

I can't figure out why this no longer works. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I searched further and found [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3808)
I realised that I was passing the page instead of a page reference to the modal window (worked with 1.4).
The correct way to do it is shown [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/modal-window?0)

Comment: You should make your solution an answer to this question and accept it.